# Как отправить файлы на сервер по нажатию по кнопке минуя или приостановив событие change, и как отправить вместе с файлом текст

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Проблема в том что как только устанавливаются файлы для отправки они сразу-же отправляются, я так понимаю связано это с событием change, мне же нужно отправлять данные по нажатию по кнопке, чтобы я смог собрать и отправит другие данные вместе с картинками, что использовать в место change или как его использовать правильно?

Код не идеален но рабочий

```html
<form id="js-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="input_file" type="file" id="js-file" name="file[]" multiple />
</form>

<button class="action"></button>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//malsup.github.io/min/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

    var description //Эту переменную нужно отправить вместе с картинками 

    $('#js-file').change(function() {
        $('#js-form').ajaxSubmit({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/upload.php',
            target: '#result',
            success: function() {
                // Закрываю модальное окно
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

И второй вопрос как добавить переменную с некоторым текстом чтобы отправить его на сервер в месте с картинками разом, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> по нажатию по кнопке

По какой кнопке?

```
//$('#js-file').change(function() {
$('#js-form button').click(function() {
    if (!$('#js-form #description').length)
        $('#js-form').append('<input type="hidden" id="description" name="description"/>');
    $('#js-form #description').val(description);
    $('#js-form').ajaxSubmit({
        ...
    });
});
```